# Speed of RubyTest in SublimeText 2

Tags: rspec, sublimetext2, ruby-test

In SublimeText with RubyTest i'm getting

> Finished in 0.24053 seconds 6 examples, 0 failures
>
> Randomized with seed 6928
>
> **[Finished in 6.4s]**

But in virtual machine(in console with bundle exec rspec) the speed is

> **Finished in 0.50997 seconds** 6 examples, 0 failures
>
> Randomized with seed 4758

Is it normal?

After change `"run_rspec_command": "bundle exec rspec {relative_path} --drb"` i got

```
No DRb server is running. Running in local process instead ...
Finished in 0.21903 seconds
6 examples, 0 failures

Randomized with seed 12822

[Finished in 6.9s]
```

Answer (score 0):

Browse to - Sublime: Preferences -> Package Settings -> RubyTest -> Settings - Default.

In that file, change

```
"run_rspec_command": "rspec {relative_path}"
```

to

```
"run_rspec_command": "bundle exec rspec {relative_path} --drb"
```

Now try executing it.